# Terraform - GCP - link an ip address to a load balancer linked to a cloud storage bucket

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

## What I want:

I would like to have a  `static.example.com` DNS records that link to a bucket in GCS containing my static images.

As I manage my DNS through Cloudflare, I think I need to use the fact that GCP can attribute me an anycast-IP , to link that IP to a GCP load balancer , that will be linked to bucket

## What I currently have:

- a bucket already created manually , named "static-images"
- the load balancer linking to said bucket, created with

  ```
  resource "google_compute_backend_bucket" "image_backend" {
    name        = "example-static-images"
    bucket_name = "static-images"
    enable_cdn  = true
  }
  ```
- the routing to link to my bucket

  ```
  resource "google_compute_url_map" "urlmap" {
    name            = "urlmap"
    default_service = "${google_compute_backend_bucket.image_backend.self_link}"

    host_rule {
      hosts        = ["static.example.com"]
      path_matcher = "allpaths"
    }

    path_matcher {
      name            = "allpaths"
      default_service = "${google_compute_backend_bucket.image_backend.self_link}"

      path_rule {
        paths   = ["/static"]
        service = "${google_compute_backend_bucket.image_backend.self_link}"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- an ip created with:

  ```
  resource "google_compute_global_address" "my_ip" {
    name = "ip-for-static-example-com"
  }
  ```

## What I'm missing:

- the terraform's equivalent to the "frontend configuration" when creating a load balancer from the web console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing a [forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/global-forwarding-rules) and [target proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-proxies).

The terraform docs on [google_compute_global_forwarding_rule](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_global_forwarding_rule.html) have a good example.

e.g.:

```
resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "default" {
  name = "default-rule"
  target = "${google_compute_target_http_proxy.default.self_link}"
  port_range = 80     // or other e.g. for ssl

  ip_address = "${google_compute_global_address.my_ip.address}"
}

resource "google_compute_target_http_proxy" "default" {  // or https proxy
  name        = "default-proxy"
  description = "an HTTP proxy"
  url_map     = "${google_compute_url_map.urlmap.self_link}"
}
```

hope this helps!